# Redirect users upon login to user's home page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know I have done this before and I have many ideas but so far from what I have done to make it work it has failed my  code looks like this: ( by the way I'm using Identity).

```
var manager = new UserManager();               
ApplicationUser user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

if (user != null)
{
    IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
}

else
{
    FailureText.Text = "Invalid username or password.";
    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

I have thought about using something like this how would i go about doing so?

```
var userId = GetUserId();

// After they log In

Response.Redirect("~/" + userId + ".aspx");
```

Currently it rediercts me back to the home page. Thank you in advance.

```
public static void RedirectToReturnUrl(string returnUrl, HttpResponse response)

{

        UserManager manager = new UserManager();
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))

        {
            response.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        else

        {
            response.Redirect("~/residentpages/" + user + ".aspx");
        }
}
```

only problem so far is that the `User.Identity.GetUserId` part, visual basic says the "User" in front of the Identity does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Mason he states what he has tried have you read the entire post.. your comment does not really help

Comment: @DJKRAZE No, he states what he would like to do. He didn't make it clear if he actually tried or what the problem was.

Comment: I read it differently as he stated what he has tried didn't work either way.. just semantics bla bla bla.. try looking here for starters http://www.primaryobjects.com/cms/article97.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE Then he should state what about it doesn't work. Either way, it's clear that more detail needs to be put into the question in order to receive useful help.

Comment: I can see your point.. but I think that a simple google search could yield many results / options in regards to which direction to take as well ...

Comment: Generally you wouldn't have a physical file devoted to each and every user, you'd build it dynamically based on the currently logged-in user. But it looks from `Response.Redirect("~/" + userId + ".aspx");` that you do want to have a file for each. Is that true?

Comment: i'm not familiar with identity but can you set a default redirect in web.config?

Comment: I'm building this site for my employees to be able to pay their monthly dues and to see if they have missed months in the past, my goal was to have a page for each of them since there is only 13 that would be using this site. That way they can have the access to paying online which I have figured out how to do, but when they login I want the site to display a page with a table on it that displays a check box for months that are paid and at the end (right side of the table) have a current total of what is due. If I can do this dynamically that would be awesome I just have never done so.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to build it in that way

Comment: Also I built code into the Identity.cs page which is where the above protocol (IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);) reports to and it looks like this

Comment: the identity page is in the original question, its at the bottom after the thank you in advance line.

Comment: You just use `RedirectToAction("ACTION_NAME", new { id = userId })`, let the engine do the work of constructing the url etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're getting slightly confused or I haven't understood you.

If you have a controller say, `ProfileController` then you will have an action on that controller called `Details`.

In this action you hit the database and get the specific profile for that user. To navigate here you do this:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
     // however you set the log in status
     return RedirectToAction("Details", "ProfileController", new { id = userId });
}
```

This will then call the action we previously discussed:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
     using (var context = contextFactory.Create())
     {
          var profile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

          return View(profile);         
     }   
}
```

I have my context built using a factory hence why I do it this way, so it can be tested etc. However, you can just use the pure context as long as you are handling its disposed.